# Custom Pop-Up for Unanswered Multiple Choice in Qualtrics Using JS

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm trying to essentially create a pop-up request response notifying a participant when a multiple choice question is unanswered but allowing them to continue (but I want to have custom text). This is what I've been playing around with, but I haven't been able to make it work (this is for question ID 28):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        // Identify this question
        var thisQuestion = $('#question{QID28}');

        // Interrupt the Next/Submit click
        $('#movenextbtn, #movesubmitbtn').bind('click', function () {
            var unanswered = false;

            // Loop through all inputs
            $('input.text', thisQuestion).each(function(i) {
                var thisValue = $(this).val();
                if(thisValue == null) {
                    unanswered = true;
                }
            });

            // Pop up confirm if we found an unanswered item
            var cont = true;
            if(unanswered == true) {
                cont =  confirm('You have an unanswered item.\nDo you want to continue?');
            }
            return cont;
        });
    });
```

In the header I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">  </script>
```

Could someone point me in the right direction or tell me what's wrong with this code? I think I don't have it properly configured to make sure that a multiple choice response is selected, but I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using JQuery however there is a very simple standard javascript answer. This is how I would make a unanswered question with alert which gives you the option to cancel or continue.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkers() {
          if (answer = 0) {
             getConfirmation();
          }
        }
        function getConfirmation(){
           var areusurebro = confirm("There is an unanswered question would you like to continue?");
           if( areusurebro == true ){
              continue;
           }
           else{
              break;
           }
        }
  </script>
```

Checkers checks if there is no value to answer. getConfirmation is a confirmation function in javascript. (To get answer one you have to make another function that sets the values to a variable like answer)

```
<script>
var answer = 0;
function clicked1() {
      answer = 1;
}
function clicked2() {
      answer = 2;
}
function clicked3() {
      answer = 3;
}
function clicked4() {
      answer = 4;
}
</script>
```

Then in your multiple choice for each answer you would put onclick="clicked1" or the corresponding number for the choice

This would also likely be in your code.

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="checkers();" />
</form>
```

From there processing the answer would likely take php or another javascript library.